# Venn diagram, simplest description

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Give the simplest description of the following Venn Diagram

$\hspace{4 cm}$[image]

#### Attempt at solution

After some time I came up with
$$ (B \cup \overline{A \oplus B \oplus C}) \backslash (A \cap B \cap C),$$
which I believe works, but I fear that it is not the most simple description. Has anyone any other suggestions perhaps ?

Comment: I may be wrong, but it looks like your displayed expression also contains the complement of the union of the three sets.

Comment: [note-- my last comment would not hold if your Venn diagram was only meant to cover the subuniverse made by the union of the three sets.]

Comment: Yeah I understand that, I honestly don't know, I am assuming that the diagram has to cover only the sub universe.

Comment: In that case your expression is OK, but as you say it *might* be expressible using fewer mentionings of sets than B,A,B,C,A,B,C [i.e. 7 mentionings], Also an issue is whether union and complement (and grouping) count among what one wants to minimize.

Comment: It's the symmetric difference of $B$ and $A\cap C$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Wow that's true, how did I not think of that ! Thank you.